# Rails skip validation on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to bypass the password validation for the user model in my application. I have the following based off some similar SO questions:

model.rb

```
attr_accessor :skip_password_validation
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true, unless: :skip_password_validation
```

controller.rb

```
@mem.skip_password_validation = true
if @mem.valid?
    #do some stuff
else
    render 'last_template'
end
```

This consistently renders the last template and returns a password validation error though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: when do you want to not validate?

Comment: When `skip_password_validation` equals a certain value. Can be `true` or `false` that detail does not matter.

Comment: try `if: -> { |mem| mem.skip_password_validation }`

Comment: try this in controller `@mem.skip_password_validation = "true"` and in model `validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true, if: "skip_password_validation.blank?"`

Comment: The code you've shown works fine, do you have any other validations?

Comment: I do have other validations but the only error being raised is `Password can't be blank` on the `:password` field.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [as mentioned in the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) `has_secure_password` adds its own validations:

> The following validations are added automatically:
>
> - Password must be present on creation
> - Password length should be less than or equal to 72 characters
> - Confirmation of password (using a password_confirmation attribute)

#### Update

[Also as mentioned in the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password) you can disable the validations by providing the `:validations` option, setting it to `false`:

> For further customizability, it is possible to supress the default validations by passing `validations: false` as an argument.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I've tried both and neither have worked. The error given is `Password can't be blank`

Comment: Ah, that's the hint I needed, I've edited my answer :)

Comment: So is there anyway to bypass this?